# Count the number of a certain text in a column in a vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a macro that takes raw data and places it into an output sheet. There is a count ticker at the top that counts the number of "Yes" in the column and places the number in a table. If I manually change the value to Yes then it works but I want it to count automatically in the macro process.

```
Range("O3").Value = "=COUNTIF(DM14:DM250, ""Yes"")"
```

Above is my formula that is working if inputted manually.

Comment: Do an `if` as you loop through `DM14:DM250`?

Comment: try `Range("O3").Formula`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the value then change the code to

```
Range("O3").Value = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(DM14:DM250, ""Yes"")")
```

And if you want to insert the formula then do as @cybernetic.nomad suggested in the comments. Change `.Value` to `.Formula`